# Conditions for roots of cubic polynomial being of same sign

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, polynomials

Given a (normed) cubic polynomial

$x^3+d_1x^2+d_2x+d_3$

with real coefficients and roots.

Which conditions I have to impose on the coefficients $d_i$ for having all the roots of the same sign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two necessary conditions are $$d_2>0\ \&\ d_1d_3>0$$

**EDIT 1**
Let $\alpha,\beta\&\gamma$ be the roots of given polynomial. We get,
$$d_2=\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha>0$$
(because each term in the above sum is positive)
$$d_1d_3=(-d_1)(-d_3)$$
$$=(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)(\alpha\beta\gamma)>0$$
(because if all roots are positive, then there sum and product are also positive, if all roots are negative, then there sum as well as product is also negative)

**EDIT 2**

As I worked out, it turns out that above mentioned conditions are sufficient as well.

Proof: Let $f(x)$ be above mentioned cubic polynomial. Then the graph of $f(x)$ will be like [image: this]with shifted origin (check by differentiating, and observe that it is monic polynomial of odd degree, so $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=-\infty$). This graph has $3$ parts, part $1$ is increasing before local maxima, part $2$ is decreasing between local extremums and part $3$ is also increasing after local minima. Also, part $3$ is convex and part $1$ is concave.

The conditions I wrote down say that $f'(0)>0$ and $f(0)f''(0)>0$. The first condition ensures that $(0,f(0))$ is in either part $1$ or part $3$ and the second condition says that if $0$ is in part $1$, then $f(0)<0$, and hence the minimum root is positive, similarly if $0$ is in part $3$, then $f(0)>0$, so the maximum root is negative.

Comment: How do you obtain them? Using Descartes' rule of signs and/or Vieta's formula?

Comment: Vieta's formula only

Comment: I already tried it and didn't see it. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Add the condition that the discriminant $18\,d_{{1}}d_{{2}}d_{{3}}-27\,{d_{{3}}}^{2}-4\,{d_{{2}}}^{3}+{d_{{1}}
}^{2}{d_{{2}}}^{2}-4\,{d_{{1}}}^{3}d_{{3}} \ge 0$, and your conditions are necessary and sufficient.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, it is given that the cubic has real coefficients and roots.

Comment: Given that, the condition is necessary and sufficient.